# SSL certificate installation on a server side

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, keytool

I am developing a mobile app. I am new to web development.

I have DNS on GoDaddy (say `app.test.com`) and have a server that only has an IP address (say `31.254.42.73`). My requests are forwarded from `app.test.com` to the IP address. I've purchased an SSL certificate which CN is `app.test.com`, on the server side I run a Jetty on Spring Boot.

SSL is imported on a server side, however I receive the following error:

> This site's certificate has expired or has been issued for a different website's address.
>   This problem may indicate an attempt to intercept the data between you and remote server.
>   Please check whether the URL in the address bar is correct.
>
> Error code 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Any ideas how can I install the SSL certificate correctly?

Comment: An SSL *certificate.* Not 'an SSL'. It's meaningless.

Comment: What does it mean that *"requests are forwarded"*? Are you using a server-side proxy (or a similar mechanism)? Or are you redirecting requests using a HTTP redirect (3xx)?

Comment: I am using HTTP redirect (3xx), thank you for editing my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is assigned to `app.test.com`, there is no way to make it work for `31.254.42.73`.

Either avoid redirecting your users to `31.254.42.73` (recommended), or purchase a new certificate for `31.254.42.73` (AFAIK, not all certificate authorities allow this).